# Exception getting access token Flutter google signing

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

Hello I'm trudging to authenticate users using [google_sign_in](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_sign_in) plugin and firebase oficial plugin, but I'm getting this error when try to authenticate.

[image: ERROR GETTING TOKEN]

Here is my code:

```
static Future<FBApi> signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignin.signIn();

final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;


  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);


  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);

  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);


  final FirebaseUser currenUser = await _auth.currentUser();

  assert(user.uid == currenUser.uid);

  return FBApi(user);
}
```

I read that same problem is caused when miss the SHA1 but I have correctly configured for production and debug key.

[image]

I update my google-services.json to before compile.

Any idea?